# I have made an application to fetch JSON data from a link. But whenever i click on the button , i don't get any data

Tags: java, android, json

I have made a button, on which, when i click the data is supposed to show up. But it's not. I don't know what's the problem. I don't get any errors and the app also works fine.

I have already given the internet permission so there no issue for that.

Here are the code files

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.apiactivity;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button click;
   public static TextView data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        click=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        data=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.fetcheddata);

        click.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                fetchData process= new fetchData();
                process.execute();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

fetchData.java

```
package com.example.apiactivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class fetchData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    String data="";
    String dataParsed="";
    String singleParsed="";
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        try {

            URL url=new URL("https://oneglobal.in/api/UserApi/Login");
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection=(HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            String line="";

            while (line!=null){

                line=bufferedReader.readLine();
                data= data + line;

            }

           JSONArray JA=new JSONArray(data);
            for (int i=0;i<JA.length();i++){
                JSONObject JO= (JSONObject) JA.get(i);

                singleParsed= "Email:" + JO.get("Email") + "\n" + "Password:" + JO.get("Password") + "\n";

                dataParsed = dataParsed+ singleParsed + "\n";
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);

        MainActivity.data.setText(this.data);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CLick me!"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:id="@+id/fetcheddata"
        android:hint="Fetched data here"
        />
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Whenever i click on the button, I want the json data on my screen in table view.

Answer (score 0):

you have to send the user name and the password to the login api 
and it is better to use retrofit or even volley to integrate with the remote api